# Bridge HCP held by the best hand at the table?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

In the game of Bridge, what is the expected number of high card points held by the player holding the most high card points at the table? $A=4$, $K=3$, $Q=2$, $J=1$.

Comment: How many cards per hand?

Comment: @Omnitic Bridge is played by four players with 13 cards each.

Comment: [Durango Bill](http://www.durangobill.com/Bridge.html) doesn't have this distribution, but it may be possible to use his code to figure it out.

Answer (score 2):

Empirically the expected maximum is about $15.1$, with a median of $15$ and mode of $14$.

The distribution looks like this:

[image]

For scores of 21 or more, the probabilities for each score are four times [those shown by Durango Bill](http://www.durangobill.com/BrPtCntStats.html)